# Get data by given date using linq

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to prepare three queries inside my mvc dbcontext class but unfortunetly i am stack on this. I would like to have three queries. First query to get only data when field DTTM (datetime) is greater than current day (from midnight). Second query the same but from two days ago (from midnight), and third query from 3 days ago (from midnight).

The DTTM field in my database is of type: datetime and some samples are:

```
2015-07-01 00:43:49.757
2015-07-01 00:44:08.397
```

this is what i did so far but its not good:

```
Dim programlogcontext As New ProgramLogContext
' Dim programlog As List(Of ProgramLog) = programlogcontext.ProgramLog.ToList

Dim programlog As List(Of ProgramLog) = programlogcontext.ProgramLog.
    Where(Function(f) f.DTTM > Date.Now.AddDays(-1)).
    ToList()
Return View(ProgramLog)
```

Comment: _"but its not good"_ Why?

Comment: after i execute this query i get this error message, anyhow i should also mark adddays(-1) but from midnight and dont know how. error message: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: [`EntityFunctions.AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412479(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ok but how to define that -1 or -2 days counting from midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date.Today` instead of `Date.Now` and  [`EntityFunctions.AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412479(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DateTime.AddDays`
 which is not supported.

```
Dim programlog As List(Of ProgramLog) = programlogcontext.ProgramLog.
    Where(Function(f) f.DTTM > EntityFunctions.AddDays(Date.Today, -1).
    ToList()
```

Comment: hi this seems to be working, but now its still missing how to get today date and midnight time so if today is 02.07.2015 i would like to be f.DTTM > 02.07.2015 00:00:00 and second case for previous day f.DTTM > 01.07.2015 00:00:00 . How to achieve that Tim?

Comment: Tim can you support on this?

Comment: @StackUser: i don't understand your requirement. If you want all from today's midnight and all from yesterday's midnight you actually want all from yestersday's midnight. So what's wrong with: `Where(Function(f) f.DTTM > EntityFunctions.AddDays(Date.Today, -1)` ? It includes also all records of today.

Comment: hi Tim, if i use this: Where(Function(f) f.DTTM > EntityFunctions.AddDays(Date.Today, -1) then i also get yesterday data, what i need is two queries one for today starting from midnight till current time  and second from yesterday midnight till current time

Comment: Then use: `Where(Function(f) f.DTTM >= EntityFunctions.AddDays(Date.Today, -1) AndAlso f.DTTM <= Date.Now)` and  `Where(Function(f) f.DTTM >= Date.Today AndAlso f.DTTM <= Date.Now)`